# Test if String Contains Substring

Tags: excel, vba

I have a substring in the column "A" of Sheet2, which I take using the LEFT Function. This is changing at every import and I'm trying to find it in the column "AI" of Sheet1. Then I want to copy the columns from "AI" to "AF" from Sheet1 and paste them in Sheet2. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub InStrDemo()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, icount As Integer
Dim LResult As String

LResult = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
LResult = Left(LResult, 4)
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row

icount = 1
For i = 2 To lastrow

If InStr(1, LCase(Range("AI" & i)), LCase(LResult)) <> 0 Then

    icount = icount + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & icount & ":E" & icount) = 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AF" & i & ":AI" & i).Value
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is showing Error ? Try debugging using F8.

Comment: one issue observed that while `instr` check was performed on Col AI, last row retrieved from Col A. If col A is empty it will effect the check. Otherwise code seems OK. However always declare variables as long while using as counter with excel rows etc.

Comment: I don't have an error. The code doesn't anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy and paste, after = it should be _ if you are trying to compare. See if it works:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & icount & ":E" & icount) = _
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AF" & i & ":AI" & i).Value
```